# Validation of Logistic Regression

Tags: r, regression, probability, logistic, interpretation

I don't have a great grasp on logistic regressions, however I am trying to analyse the factors that determine plant naturalisation

Dataset can be found here
https://filebin.net/yoi8hafn1jj3t2tf

The response (naturalised)(nat) is binary and contains three categorical predictors - cold.tolerant, period.introduced, and Number Planted (bin) which has been log transformed in 1-10, 10-100, 100-1000, 1000-10000, 10000-100000

My final model is

```
M2 <- glm(nat ~ cold.tolerant + bin + period.introduced, data=Plants, family = binomial)
```

With a poor AIC of 614.25

I have determined the probabilities using

```
> exp(coef(M2))/(1+exp(coef(M2)))
       (Intercept)   cold.tolerantyes        bin(10,100]     bin(100,1e+03]   bin(1e+03,1e+04]   bin(1e+04,1e+05] 
       0.001316148        0.724736511        0.793515968        0.831953836        0.955718848        0.975876834 
period.introduced2 period.introduced3 
       0.748293170        0.820253204
```

These values seem quite high, especially since a small number of plants actually naturalised. Additionally, I am having trouble interepreting it, for example how to I read the prob for period introduced 1, or cold tolerant no if they are incorparated in the intercept

These are the raw number of plant naturalised

```
> table(Plants$cold.tolerant, Plants$nat)
     
         0    1
  no   177    3
  yes 1161   98

> table(Plants$bin, Plants$nat)
               
                  0   1
  (0,10]        334   4
  (10,100]      483  19
  (100,1e+03]   325  16
  (1e+03,1e+04] 171  48
  (1e+04,1e+05]  25  14

> table(Plants$period.introduced, Plants$nat)
   
      0   1
  1 294   5
  2 224  19
  3 820  77
```

Do the results of the probabilities look realistic? Any additional interpretation would be greatly appreciated, as I am struggling to wrap my head around it.

Thanks

Comment: [Binning data is very bad practice.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/397258/1352) And you can't interpret an AIC in isolation, you can only compare AICs between models. Finally, I would not look at parameters, but rather evaluate your model on a holdout data set and assess the predicted probabilities against the true outcome using proper [tag:scoring-rules].

Comment: I have removed the binning which has resulted in the following


> exp(coef(M2))/(1+exp(coef(M2)))
       (Intercept)   cold.tolerantyes     number.planted period.introduced2 period.introduced3 
       0.003700915        0.820091758        0.500031651        0.790664235        0.831625724 


How do I now interpret the probability of the number planted, since it now a continuous data set?
Sorry I am not familiar will scoring rules, could you please explain further?
Thanks

Comment: You can interpret your model by predicting a new data point using `predict(...,type="response")`, which will give you probabilities. Do this on a holdout data set. [The scoring rules tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info) contains pointers to literature.

Comment: Thank you, I always get stuck with binary data, especially with multiple categorical predictors